# centering the logo and company name on the top of the web page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center the company logo and the name of the company on top of the web page. The name of the company should also be at the center of the logo. Right now, it is at the bottom of the logo. This is what I have so far:

```
<style>
 .logo img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

    </style>

<html>
 <hr style="height:5px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray" />
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="download.png" /> This is Test Company Name
        </div>
        <hr style="height:12px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray"/>

</html>
```

This is how the image looks like:

[image]

I want to center the logo and the company name.

Comment: do you need the height 100vh?

Comment: height can me more or less.

Comment: if you remove the height 100vh it will be centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
      .logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
     .logo img {
      width: 100px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1100px) {
      .logo {
        flex-direction: column; 
        height: 100vh;
      }
    
      .logo img {
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
```

```html
<hr style="height:5px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray" />
<div class="logo">
     <img src="download.png" /> This is Test Company Name
</div>
<hr style="height:12px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray"/>
```

Comment: how can I center the company name with the logo. Right now the name appears at the bottom of the logo

Comment: @anjali updated the code